# Chihuahua is almost 20 pounds

Tags: dogs, health, weight

I've been trying to get her to lose weight, but she acts so sad.

The dog is a chi-weenie, and only eats oscar meyer's wieners. This questions is dead serious and I really need help. She is 8 years old and I don't want her dying young due to obesity.

Comment: Get her to a vet ASAP.

Comment: And get her on a diet, and stick to it. Else your dog will die of obesity.

Comment: What is the question you're asking here? How to get her to lose weight? What diet is appropriate for the dog? Is a checkup required?

Comment: You strictly only feed your pet hot dogs?  You don't deserve to have a pet.

Answer (score 1):

Dogs, or any animal really, do not die from obesity, but symptoms that are often comorbid with obesity may shorten the animal's lifespan, like heart disease, high blood pressure, diabetes, etc. A checkup at your vet will determine if your dog has any of these other symptoms, and appropriate action can be taken to help with those conditions.

Ultimately though, because obesity does seem to increase the risk for these conditions, and because being obese can be harder on the joints and body, decreasing the dog's quality of life, it's healthier for the dog to lose weight. Like with humans, losing weight is difficult. Consult with your vet about a diet regimen and stick to it. No extra treats or snacks, and definitely no more human food, like Oscar Meyer weiners. Perhaps more importantly, exercise the dog regularly. Not only does exercise burn more calories, but it is linked to many health benefits include reducing the risk of many of those symptoms I mentioned, like heart disease and high blood pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Your vet is going to provide you with the best solution to transitioning your dog off of hotdogs and onto dog appropriate food, and you'll probably be more inclined to stick to it after discussing it with a professional.

> I've been trying to get her to lose weight, but she acts so sad.

It sucks to feel that our pets are sad, I know, but you have to do what's best for them.

My dog was diagnosed with pancreatitis about a month ago. He was vomiting daily, usually with blood in the mix. He could no longer eat anything other than his low-fat prescription food.

It was a transition for us as well. He didn't eat human food on a regular basis, but I'd often feed him crusts off of my pizza, or allow him to have a small scoop of peanut butter when he took his medication for seizures.  Once he was diagnosed, he could no longer eat any of those things. He would still come and sit by me and wait for me to give him small table scraps.  Within a few weeks, he had moved on and now just lays down next to me instead of giving me his starving dog eyes while I eat.

You need to be the pack leader. You need to set the tone. Do not be sad for your dog, because you'll be giving her a healthier, longer life to enjoy things other than just hot dogs. Your dog will transition and will also be happy if you are happy.